# Linq Query dinamica entre dois contextos

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Estou tentando retornar a sequinte consulta sql porém sem sucesso.

```
SQL=
select IDEstado, COUNT(IDEstado) from PessoaEstado w 
join Nucleo.dbo.Estado e on e.ID = w.IDEstado
where IDPessoaMaster = 46
group by IDEstado

Code=
var dbApp = new App();

var dbNucleo = new Nucleo();
var estados = (from e in dbNucleo.Estado
                select new { e.ID, e.Nome }).ToArray();

var result = (from w in db.PessoaEstado
              join e in estados on w.IDEstado equals e.ID
              where w.IDPessoaMaster == IDPessoaMaster
              group new { w, e } by new
              {
                  e.Nome
              } into z
              select new
              {
                nome = z.Key.Nome;
                qtd = z.Count()
              }).OrderByDescending(x => x.qtd);

return result.ToList<dynamic>();
```

retorna o erro:

> Não foi possível criar um valor constante de tipo 'Tipo anônimo'.
>   Apenas tipos primitivos ou tipos de enumeração têm suporte nesse
>   contexto.

Comment: Qual linha ocorre o erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça [`Linq to Objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx)

Você está trabalhando em contextos ([`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)) diferentes e a melhor solução seria trazer em objeto e ai relacionar com [`Linq To Objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx), um outro ponto a observar é trazer os dados e não colocar no Trancking (Cache) do [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)([`AsNoTracking`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx))

***Como***

```
IList<Estado> Estados = dbNucleo.Estado.AsNoTracking().ToList();
IList<PessoaEstado> PessoasEstados = db.PessoaEstado.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

---

***Linq***

```
var resultado = PessoaEstado
                .Where(x=>x.IDPessoaMaster == 46)
                .Join(Estado, p => p.IDEstado, e => e.ID, (p, e) => new { p, e })
                .GroupBy(x => x.p.IDEstado)                
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    IDEstado = s.Key,
                    CountEstado = s.Count()
                }).ToList();
```

***Rodando Exemplo - Dados Fictícios***

```
IList<PessoaEstado> PessoaEstado = new List<PessoaEstado>();
PessoaEstado.Add(new PessoaEstado() { IDEstado = 1, IDPessoaMaster = 46 });
PessoaEstado.Add(new PessoaEstado() { IDEstado = 2, IDPessoaMaster = 46 });
PessoaEstado.Add(new PessoaEstado() { IDEstado = 1, IDPessoaMaster = 46 });

IList<Estado> Estado = new List<Estado>();
Estado.Add(new Estado() { ID = 1 });
Estado.Add(new Estado() { ID = 2 });


var resultado = PessoaEstado
   .Where(x=>x.IDPessoaMaster == 46)
   .Join(Estado, p => p.IDEstado, e => e.ID, (p, e) => new { p, e })
   .GroupBy(x => x.p.IDEstado)                
   .Select(s => new
   {
        IDEstado = s.Key,
        CountEstado = s.Count()
   }).ToList();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que ele vai querer a resposta mais dentro do código dele.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, o que mais pega no código proposto por ele que na SQL ele ta agrupando pelo IDEstado e no Linq ela ta agrupando por Nome, eu pensei, em fazer um exemplo minimo para que ele tivesse a visão que contextos diferentes precisam trabalhar com `Linq to Objects`, talvez (**suposição**) ele colocando `ToArray()` nessa linha `var result = (from w in db.PessoaEstado.ToArray() ...` e continuar do mesmo jeito consigo uma solução mas, recai no que eu mesmo mostrei. Bom ele ainda não fez interação, estou nesse aguardo ou qualquer edição na sua questão, obrigado pela dica ...